# If statement returning false result using date and strtotime

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm trying to use an if statement to say "If today is between two dates, do this..." etc.

It's not working, and I'm at a total loss because as far as I can see - it SHOULD work!

```
if (date('d/m/y', strtotime('now')) >= date('d/m/y', strtotime('1 January 2021')) && date('d/m/y', strtotime('now')) <= date('d/m/y', strtotime('31 January 2021'))):
    echo 'true';
else:
    echo 'false';
endif;
```

Today is 3rd of December 2020 - so why is it telling me this statement is true?

PS. It does work if I change it to either, or both `> 30th December 2020` and `< 1st February 2021` - but I'm wary to do this in case it's just a glitch and I've made an obvious coding mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date('d/m/y')` gives you a string like `30/11/20`. Comparing dates in this format really means you're comparing strings, which only works if the dates are in YYYYMMDD (or YYYY-MM-DD) format.

It's much easier to just use `strtotime()` to turn the English-like date into a Unix timestamp (just a big integer) and compare them directly:

```
if ( 
    strtotime('now') >= strtotime('1 January 2021')
        &&
    strtotime('now') <= strtotime('31 January 2021')
) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: This answer has already been posted 15 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. It's not December 3rd now it's the first of December.

The problem you have is because you are trying to compare strings.
Date() returns strings and as far as I know no programming language can properly (whatever properly means in this context) compare > or < with strings. It's either === or !==.

So use the Unix times in the comparison since that is numeric and much easier for the computer to understand.

```
$now = strtotime('now');
$start = strtotime('1 January 2021');
$end = strtotime('31 January 2021');

if ($now >= $start && $now <= $end):
    echo 'true';
else:
    echo 'false';
endif;
```

https://3v4l.org/KAvQ2

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for all your date-related calculations. Don't use the old `strtotime()` or `date()` unless you really know what you're doing.

With `DateTime` class it's really simple:

```
<?php

$start = new DateTime('1 January 2021');
$end = new DateTime('31 January 2021');
$today = new DateTime();
if($today >= $start && $today <= $end){
    echo 'In between';
} else {
    echo 'outside or range';
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/pEdLM)

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with following.

```
if (strtotime(date('d/m/y', strtotime('now'))) >= strtotime(date('d/m/y', strtotime('1 January 2021'))) && strtotime(date('d/m/y', strtotime('now'))) <= strtotime(date('d/m/y', strtotime('31 January 2021')))):
    echo 'true';
else:
    echo 'false';
endif;
```

Comment: [@Sachin J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9177613/sachin-j) Doesn't work if you change it to Nov 1st 2020 and Jan 31st 2021, which SHOULD return true - but doesn't... I'm so confused!

Comment: Why do you take a string date and convert it to Unix time, the convert the Unix time to string, and then convert the string to Unix time again.

Comment: @Andreas it's a CRC technique.

Comment: @MarkusAO If that is the case then I would advice on using a format that **does not change** the value. https://3v4l.org/0G8Ko

Comment: @Andreas I'd personally add in a routine that logs a hash of the values each time they are unnecessarily converted back and forth, and finally converts the hashes to binary and sums them up and divides by zero to ensure zero mistakes.